# Subdivision schemes: how to create diagrams from subdivision masks?

Tags: geometry, interpolation

I came across this interesting example on [cambridge website](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2004/AdvGraph/exercise2.html):

> The Catmull-Clark bivariate subdivision scheme is a bivariate
> generalization of the univariate `1/8 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]` subdivision
> scheme. It creates new vertices as blends of old vertices in the
> following ways:
>
> [subdivision scheme diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXmBD.png)
>
> Provide similar diagrams for the bivariate generalization of the
> univariate four-point interpolating subdivision scheme `1/16 [-1, 0, 9, 16, 9, 0,-1]`.

I have now spent some time researching and reading some papers on the subject and basically I found out that such such mask weights are calculated based on how far away they are. (The further away, the weaker the weighting).

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to go from a subdivision mask of this bivariate generalization of the four-point interpolation scheme `1/16 [-1, 0, 9, 16, 9, 0,-1]` to a similar diagram like in the example above.

Any tipps or hints are much appreciated